# Can I ignore a GPO from another GPO?

Tags: active-directory, printer, group-policy

I have 10 users and 10 computers and 5 printers.  9 of the computers are workstations and the 10th is our accounting server.  Each user has a unique set of network drive mappings and printer mappings.  I deploy printers using Print Management -> Deploy to Group Policy.  I deploy network drives using User Preferences in the GPO.  I am using GPO deployment because I want to eliminate the logon script.

Everything works great until the user log onto the accounting server through terminal services.  There I want a Computer based GPO to map specific network drives and printers for that server.  My problem is that I can't find a way to ignore the User Printer GPOs when a user logs onto that server.  For the network drives I can use targeting which works great.  But my method of printer deployment has no targeting option that I can find.

Is there a way to allow the GPO for that server to ignore my User Drive and Printer GPOs only when that user logs into that server through Terminal Services?  If not, does anyone have any other ideas aside from writing a logon script?

Thanks

-Craig

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure the appropriate User Configuration settings in the GPO linked to the accounting computer OU and configure Loopback Policy processing in Replace mode. This will replace the users normal GPO settings with the user settings in the GPO linked to the computer OU. I would recommend placing the accounting computer in it's own OU and linking a GPO to the OU.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782810(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Vote++.  Loopback processing - created for this very reason.